# Enable Diagnostics Logs for App Service using ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template, azure-diagnostics

I am trying to setup enable diagnostics logs for app service using portal, which is working fine as below :

[image]

The same settings i am trying create using ARM Template but it is not working.
My ARM Template looks like below :

[image]

Is there anything wrong with settings or any other ways to enable logs ?
Anyone help is appreciated.

Regards,
Dipti Mamidala

Answer (score 2):

In the resources array of the resource for which you want to enable Diagnostic Logs, add a resource of type `[resource namespace]/providers/diagnosticSettings`.

Example :

```
"resources": [
  {
    "type": "providers/diagnosticSettings",
    "name": "[concat('Microsoft.Insights/', parameters('settingName'))]",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[/*resource Id for which Diagnostic Logs will be enabled>*/]"
    ],
    "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
    "properties": {
      "name": "[parameters('settingName')]",
      "storageAccountId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]",
      "eventHubAuthorizationRuleId": "[parameters('eventHubAuthorizationRuleId')]",
      "eventHubName": "[parameters('eventHubName')]",
      "workspaceId": "[parameters('workspaceId')]",
      "logs": [ 
        {
          "category": "/* log category name */",
          "enabled": true,
          "retentionPolicy": {
            "days": 0,
            "enabled": false
          }
        }
      ],
      "metrics": [
        {
          "category": "AllMetrics",
          "enabled": true,
          "retentionPolicy": {
            "enabled": false,
            "days": 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Read more here in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-enable-diagnostic-logs-using-template)

Update : To set the value of `Web Server logging` use the below example

```
             "properties": {
                "applicationLogs": {
                  "Storage": {
                    "level": "Verbose"
                  }
                },
                "httpLogs": {
                  "fileSystem": {
                             }
                          }
                       }
```

If you want `Storage` or `fileSystem` use any one of above

Comment: I have checked this documentation, can you please let me know how to set web server logging in above code ?

Comment: @DiptiMamidala web server loggin in ? What do you mean ?

Comment: If you see in the above portal screenshot, there is one section called "web server logging" which I would like to set from ARM Template.

Comment: @DiptiMamidala i have updated the answer , check it out

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by setting the *httpLogs* and *httpLoggingEnabled* properties.

This is the config resource nested within a site resource:

```
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "type": "config",
      "name": "logs",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "applicationLogs": {
          "azureBlobStorage": {
            "level": "information",
            "retentionInDays": 15
          }
        },
        "httpLogs": {
          "fileSystem": {
            "retentioninMb": 35,
            "retentioninDays": 15,
            "enabled": true
          }
        },
        "requestTracingEnabled": true,
        "requestTracingExpirationTime": "9999-12-31T23:59:00Z",
        "remoteDebuggingEnabled": false,
        "httpLoggingEnabled": true,
        "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 34,
        "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": true
      }
    }
  ]
```